# How to mount android oem.img?

Tags: android, mount, rom

I am trying to see content of *oem.img* partiton, this partition is mostly found in Motorola's "moto" series. I got the ROM from [stock firmware athene](https://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g4-plus/how-to/stock-rom-npjs25-93-14-4-march-1-t3608138).

I tried `$ file oem.img` which returned:

> oem.img: Android sparse image, version: 1.0, Total of 167969 4096-byte output blocks in 181 input chunks

Next I tried to decompress it with `$ simg2img oem.img oem.raw` and then I tried to mount it with
`$ sudo mount -o loop oem.raw /mnt/oem` but it raises the following error:

> mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop5, missing codepage or helper program, or other error

So I tried mounting it as ext4 and f2fs using `-t ext4` and `-t f2fs` option but both gave the same error. Are there any step that I am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a port of `libsparse` that someone made just for that purpose:

> Tool to convert Android sparse images to raw images.
>
> Since image tools are not part of Android SDK, this standalone port of AOSP libsparse aims to avoid complex building chains.

https://github.com/anestisb/android-simg2img#readme